# Not able to push message to one of the queue silently failing, at the same time able to send to other queues

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to put message to Azure service bus queue, and using `QueueClient` to send the message. But it is not sending message to queue. But it is not even giving any error or exception. It is silently failing not sure what is going wrong here.

```
queueClient.Send(message);
```

This line is not throwing exception but not even sending message for Q1, but able to send message to Q2 in same service bus namespace.

QueueClient is from  `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueClient`.

Thanks

Comment: `QueueClient` doesn't have synchronous APIs, only async. Are you sure it's not some sort of extension method? Also, if it send to one queue and not another, check the queue. Maybe it's at fault. Try re-creating the queue and see if the issue persists. If it does, share a repro to see exactly what's done in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out whether there is any autocomplete option enabled because if there is no exception or any error then it might be the problem. Also, check whether you have used any autocomplete function. If it so, that function would delete all of your message and remove it.